GitHub GraphQL query issues by status within project
First, I did review this question, and mine is different.
I want a script to retrieve JSON output equivalent to this page, which works in a browser:
https://github.com/orgs/$owner/projects/$project/views/$view?filterQuery=milestone%3A%22Milestone+Name%22+status%3A%22Project+Status%22
where "Milestone Name" and "Project Status" are, like $owner, $project and $view, known to the script beforehand.
The important part is that the status is associated with the project, not with the issue or the milestone. That's why this does not duplicate the question I linked above.
I can get to the ProjectV2View node with:
query {
  organization(login:"$owner") {
    projectV2(number:$project) {
      view(number:$view) {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

But I don't know how to even list issues in that view, never mind filter them as above. Help is much appreciated!
